# QField sync issue

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I am trying to use QField to collect and sync data back to QGIS via QField Cloud. Everything appears to work well (packaging, upload to the cloud, collection in QField and pushing changes) until the final transfer or synchronisation of data from the cloud to desktop. I can see that changes have been made on the cloud however QFieldSync does not appear to recognise this. When the synchronisation function is used QFieldSync provides a message indicating the files are already synchronised.

I have followed instructions to the letter and tried various packages, combinations of files and feature classes, uninstalling and reinstalling QFieldSync all without success. I am using the latest versions of everything as of 18/9/23.

Looking at various questions on this site the question appears to relatively common. Is there something simple I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.